# Find a Defining Equation for the Golden Ratio: $(1 + \sqrt{5})/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Find a defining equation for the golden ratio: $(1 + \sqrt{5})/2$. Furthermore, find its norm in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$. It seems like it would be simple, but I am still new to quadratic field. Could I get some aid on how to start and solve this? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean a defining equation?

Comment: That's part of what I'm unsure about. I know that in physics, defining equations are equations that define new quantities in terms of base quantities (kinda self-explanatory in this context), but I am unsure about how this applies to number theory.

Comment: It’s the positive root of $x^2-x-1=0$, if that’s what you mean by a defining equation. You can deduce this from the definition of the golden ratio, or you can set $x=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$, multiply by $2$, subtract $1$, square, and divide out the common factor of $4$.

Comment: If a quadratic with rational coefficients has this as a root, it also has the conjugate as a root. Now get the coefficients of the monic quadratic by coefficient of $x$ is the negative of the sum of the roots, and constant term is product of the roots.

Comment: Recall that the golden ratio can be defined as the real number $x$ such that if you remove a $1\times 1$ square from an $x\times 1$ rectangle, the rectangle that remains is similar to the original. This means that $$\frac{x}1=\frac1{x-1}\;,$$ from which $x^2-x-1=0$ follows at once.

Comment: That makes sense. How do I use this to find the norm in $Q[√5]$?

Comment: I don't know why the term defining equation was used when they are asking for what is usually called "the" minimal polynomial.

Comment: That threw me off as well, which is why I had no idea where to start.

Comment: Yay! A downvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x= (1 + √5)/2$$
$$2x= 1 + √5$$
$$2x-1=  √5$$
$$4x^2-4x +1=  5$$
$$4x^2-4x -4=  0$$
$$x^2-x -1= 0$$
gives one possibility, though the squaring has introduced another root, namely $x= (1 - √5)/2$.  If you multiply these two roots together you will get $-1$, the norm.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm for more on finding norms

Comment: The norm is not nonnegative?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Unlike a distance norm, a field norm can be negative

Answer (score 1):

$\!\!\!\begin{align}{\rm Recall}\ \ w = a + b\sqrt{n}\rm \ \ has\ \ {\bf norm}\  &=\: w\:\cdot\: w' = (a + b\sqrt{n})\ \cdot\: (a - b\sqrt{n})\ =\: a^2\! - n\: b^2\\[4pt]
{\rm and,\ furthermore,\ }w\rm \ \ has\ \ {\bf trace}\ &=\: w+w' =  (a + b\sqrt{n}) + (a - b\sqrt{n})\: =\:  2a\end{align}$

Now apply Vieta $\ (x\!-\!w)(x\!-\!w') = x^2 - (w\!+\!w')x + ww' =\, x^2 - 2a\, x + a^2\!-nb^2$

Answer (score 0):

The golden ratio is one of the solutions to $x^2-x-1=0$. (I presume this is what you mean by "defining equation.")

Its norm would be $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - 5 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = -1$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got those answers? Understanding the solution is important for me. Thanks!

Comment: The norm is $-1$. It is the product of our number and its conjugate,

Comment: Is "our number"  $(1+√5)/2$?

Comment: @Crazed: Yes, it is.

Comment: How does this relate to $Q[√5]$? (Sorry for questions that may seem obvious, I am still new to this topic)

Comment: Sorry, I flipped signs in my conjugate calculation. It is in fact -1

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you split a length in two. You split it according to the golden ratio if the ratio of the larger length $L$ to the smaller length $l$ is equal to the ratio of the total length $L+l$ to the larger length $L$.

In formulae, if $L=xl$,
$$x=\frac{(x+1)l}{lx}\iff x^2=x+1.$$

The norm of an element in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 5)$ is the product of all the conjugates of this element. If $x=a+b\sqrt 5$ ($a,b\in\mathbf Q$), we have $N(x)=a^2-5b^2$. Thus the norm of the *Golden ratio* is equal to $-1$.

Comment: I understand this, but I am still unclear on how to find the norm.

Comment: @Crazed: I've added some details for the norm.

Answer (score 0):

How about the original construction from the Greeks?

Let $a, b, c$ be the sides of a right triangle with $c$ as hypotenuse and $b:a=2:1$.  Then:

$b^2=c^2-a^2=(c+a)(c-a)$ (the difference of squares factorization is easily proved by the geometric methods used by the Greeks).

$c-a=(c+a)-b$ (from $b=2a$, hypothesis)

So

$b^2=(c+a)(c+a-b)$

From the cross product rule for proportions (again known since ancient times):

$(c+a)/b=b/(c+a-b)$

This represents whatcwe now call a "golden division" (a term invented later), and the ratio in the last equatyin is both $(c+a)/b$ and $b/(c-a)$.  These formulas are commonly used to geometrically construct the golden ratio, for example in Ptolemy's construction of the regular pentagon/pentagram.